# c# and sql how to show selected item price in textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvGog.png)

what i need is when i selected item in combobox to show in listbox and his price in the cost textbox and sum price if i choose another items

this is my code
public void fill_listbox()
{
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select TestCost,TestName from TestTbl", con);
DataSet dt = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dt, "TestName");
TestidCb.DataSource = dt.Tables["TestName"];
TestidCb.DisplayMember = "TestName";
TestidCb.ValueMember = "TestCost";
TestidCb.Text = "Select NorTest";

```
    }






    string TR = "";
    int GrdCost = 0;
    private void OkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LabidCb.SelectedIndex == -1 )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("select the Test And Lab");
        }
        else
        {
            TR = TR + "|" + TestidCb.Text;
            TestTb.Text = TR;
            GrdCost = GrdCost +Cost;
            CostTb.Text = "" + GrdCost;
            //TestidCb.SelectedIndex = -1;
            //LabidCb.SelectedIndex = -1;
            //StNameTb.Text = "";
            Reset1();
        }
```

}

Comment: First your query only return "TestName", you have to change the query to get all the data.

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit, at the moment there are to many questions; Where would we find that price? is it another column in the TestTbl? Is TestName unique in that table? are you asking about querying  the data or events on the combobox ... or even putting more data in the combobox

Comment: the price is in testTbl and yes testname is unique in the table and i show all testname data in combobox iwhent price to be showing also in texbox and add each item i salected

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started. The `ExecuteNonQuery` has been removed because it serves no purpose.

I added "TestPrice" to the `SELECT` statement.

I have bound the DataTable to the combobox instead of added items in a loop.

I set both a DisplayMember and ValueMember. The user will only see TestName, but the value of the items is the price.

```
public void fill_list()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select TestName, TestPrice from TestTbl";
        
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            
            TestidCb.DataSource = dt;
            TestidCb.DisplayMember = "TestName";
            TestidCb.ValueMember = "TestPrice";
        }           
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Now, in the selected changed event for instance, you can get both TextName and the price and do whatever you need:

```
private void TestidCb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
    string price = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show($"Name: {name}, Price: {price}");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanatory what i needed is when i show that test name in textbox how to sum each item price  and price i also in database

Comment: @zack I still don't understand. Your question seems to imply there is a one-to-one relationship between each item and price. It doesn't make sense to sum one price. You will need to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I added an image that defines what I need

Answer (score 0):

create a class myProductListItem having 2 properties, name and price

get both the name and the price in your query (select testname, price from TestTbl)

put these in an instance of myProductListItem and put that in your combobox.items

```
        public class myListItem
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new myListItem(){Name = "myname",Price = 10});
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selected = comboBox1.SelectedItem as myListItem;
            if (selected != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text = selected.Price.ToString();

            }
        }
```